# Class "Redis" Not Found laravel 8, using phpredis

Tags: laravel, redis, phpredis

I am using laravel 8, and it is throwing error, when ever I tried to run:

`php artsian config:clear`

On laravel, this is my config value (because I am trying to use phpredis):

```
'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),
```

I could use redis-cli and ping at the moment. Not, just that I could hit the following endpoint successfully.

```
    public function testRedis()
    {
        Redis::set('ping','pong');
        $ping = Redis::get('ping');
        dd($ping);
    }
```

It prints out `pong` successfully.

but I am receiving class `Redis` not found. Whenever I tried to run, `php artisan config:clear`

Full error looks like this:

```
  Class "Redis" not found

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php:75
     71▕      * @throws \LogicException
     72▕      */
     73▕     protected function createClient(array $config)
     74▕     {
  ➜  75▕         return tap(new Redis, function ($client) use ($config) {
     76▕             if ($client instanceof RedisFacade) {
     77▕                 throw new LogicException(
     78▕                     extension_loaded('redis')
     79▕                         ? 'Please remove or rename the Redis facade alias in your "app" configuration file in order to avoid collision with the PHP Redis extension.'

      +10 vendor frames 
  11  app/Models/Setting.php:34
      Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic()

  12  app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php:37
      App\Models\Setting::getCachedValue()
```

and my `App\Models\Setting` looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

class Setting extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $table = 'settings';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $dates = ['created_at','updated_at'];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d', // Change your format
        'updated_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
    ];

    const STRIPE_ENVIRONMENT = ['test', 'live'];

    public static function getCachedValue(){
        return Cache::rememberForever('settings', function () {
            return Setting::pluck('key_value', 'key_name');
        });
    }

    public static function updateCachedSettingsData(){
        Cache::forget('settings');
        self::getCachedValue();
    }
}
```

What, I might be doing wrong here.
**#PS**: This line on my `config/app` is commented.

```
// 'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
```

Comment: It looks like the PHP Redis extension is not installed, You can check if the Redis PHP extension is installed & enable. Redis is installed, configured & running.

Answer (score 44):

you must specify "REDIS CLIENT" in your .env file after installation

```
composer require predis/predis
```

in the .env file add these lines

```
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_CLIENT=predis
```

Comment: Thanks, `REDIS_CLIENT=predis` was missing

Comment: in the database.php file, replace the following line:
'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis')
to:
'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis')

Answer (score 15):

Okay, I found the issue, there was updated pushed to ubuntu, and with this update looks like default php was updated to php8.0, previously it was 7.4. So, running following command fix the issue.

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-redis
```

It looks like it was missing redis extension for php 8.0

Comment: `Unable to locate package php8.1-redis`

Comment: @Pathros me too having same issue unable to locate

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php8.1-redis` seems to work for me Ubuntu 20.x LTS

Comment: Just look the package name with `apt search php | grep redis`. then install the package

Answer (score 0):

add this to `app.php` file

```
  'aliases' => Facade::defaultAliases()->merge([
        'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
    ])->toArray(),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I was able to resolve it by installing Redis and Redis Server. Follow these steps:

**Install Redis for PHP:**

```bash
sudo apt-get install php8.3-redis
```

Check your PHP version using `php -v` and substitute `8.3` with your actual PHP version.

**Install Redis Server:**

```bash
sudo apt install redis-server
```

Answer (score 0):

you must specify "REDIS CLIENT" in your .env file after installation

```
npm install predis/predis
```

in your .env file add this lines

```
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_CLIENT=predis
```